# How to use ng-cloak in angular js properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ngcloak

I have a basic question about `ng-cloak` In my page I have some places where are I binded some data using angular js {{ }}. Now, I used ng-cloak directive in the body tag and because of this the whole page is going blank for sometime until the page gets loaded, I just want the binded data to be hidden until the pages gets loaded.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what is the error you are getting in console? after ading ng-cloak?

Comment: I think you have to add a piece of css. I also had this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `ng-cloak` directive can be used on any html elements, so you probably just need to use it on an element which is a closer ancestor to where you have your binding expression, rather than on the body tag. For example, if your binding is inside a paragraph tag:

```
<p ng-cloak>{{ someVar }}</p>
```

It might be a good idea to place it on the element where the controller is defined, so all bindings within are hidden until angular is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use ng-bind instead of {{someVar}} like this

```
<p ng-bind="someVar"></p>
```

or if the var has some html content then use ng-bind-html.
Hope this solves your problem.